# In java we can compile more than one source file but why cannot execute more then on .class file at a time

Tags: java

In java we can compile more than one source file but why cannot execute more then one .class file at a time
For the example like:
 if we compile a program by using command prompt then we can compile multiple source file at a time. by using *

```
             Ex-        Javac F*.java Test.java
```

here F is used for name of source file which strt from f and test is another file.
but why we can't execute multiple .class file at a time.by using

```
                      Java test test1 
                       or
                      Java T*
```

or any other way on cmd.
please give me solution or provide some reason why not.

Comment: Google the phrase "classpath" and semantics for the `main(...)` method.

Comment: What do you mean by executing multiple classes? Run them at the same time? There's threads for that.

Comment: Suppose you start two applications at once, and both write to the console and expect an answer from you. How would you intend this to work? Why not simply open two command line windows, and run each app in its window?

Answer (score 3):

An interesting non-sequitur you have there. I can buy multiple cars but I can only drive one at a time, why?

Comment: Its OK your statement is correct but i want answer correspond to program and I want reason behind this means what is processing going on in JVM.How its compile more then one source files and why not its able to execute more then one .class files

Answer (score 0):

Because one thread can have one flow of control at a time. In java when JVM starts one background thread starts, along with this thread one more thread starts that is responsible to run main method of your class. If you are trying to run multiple classes at a time means you are trying to have two separate control flow for that single thread at a time, That is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. "Execute" is "execute", and "compile" is "compile". You can execute one file per time and test it, but you have to compile many of them. You can build many bicycles in your factory, but you can only ride one per time.